# Spring Boot 1.4.3 Embedded Tomcat NoSuchMethodError StringManager.getManager

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have update my project to use Spring BOOT 1.4.3. The code compiles and runs without issues from Eclipse Neon 1.
But when I run from command line

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests

java -jar myweb\target\my-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get runtime error and tomcat is not starting

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager;
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.<clinit>(LifecycleBase.java:43) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
```

Please can you tell why? How to find which tomcat is used at runtime, as my understand is that 8.5.6 is having compile scope(?)

Please help. If the suggestion is to use tomcat.version in properties of POM file or add tomcat-juli dependency, then please help me understand why it is required?

*Impatient stackoverflow'ers dont just flog new comers only because you can do. You can easily ask if you want my POM, but I used just spring-boot-starter-web thats it.*

Comment: Apparently you haven't only used `spring-boot-starter-web` as something is pulling in another dependency which breaks stuff. So basically this question contains too little information to be able to give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of problem, it's often due to multiple jar having the same class inside your classpath, so :

1. Find where this class / method could come from, by opening the type popup (CTRL + SHIFT + T in Eclipse). It will display you every jar in your classpath that contains the class.
2. Open the class in each jar to see which one contains your method and which one don't.
3. Display the dependency hierarchy of your project with `mvn dependency:tree`
4. If the 2 jars are in your classpath, you might exclude the one that don't contain the method.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted as answer. Eclipse identified that the class exists in 2 jars. The issue was tomcat-util jar was added as a  dependency in a dependent project/module. It was version 8.0.27 and boot is getting 8.5.6. Hence the conflict